# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T-STRING

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to complete a final term project and I am running into errors.  Here is the story, I am attempting to create a database in mtsql php with tables and when trying to load the local file I am getting the following error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Franchise' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\franchisecalllogdb.php on line 37

Line 37 looks fine, I am really trying to get an A on this project but I am not confident I am doing this right.

Here is my code using Notepad ++

```
<?php
//connect to MySQL
include("inc_connect_local.php");
mysql_select_db("Franchise Call Log");
$caller_info = "CREATE TABLE caller_info (
caller_id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,
first_name varchar(35) not null, 
Last_name varchar(35) not null, 
franchise varchar(25) not null)
";
$results = mysql_query($caller_info) or die (mysql_error());

//create "caller_call_record" table
$caller_call_record = "CREATE TABLE caller_call_record (
(call_record_id int(11) not null,
Call_Description varchar(50),
franchise_id int(10) not null,
Email varchar(40) not null, 
Username varchar(25) primary key not null)
";
$results = mysql_query($caller_escalation)
or die(mysql_error());

//create "caller_escalation" table
$caller_escalation = "CREATE TABLE caller_escalation (
call_escalation_id int(11) unsigned auto_increment not null, 
Second_Level varchar(5) not null, 
caller_id int(11) unsigned not null, 
PRIMARY KEY(call_escalation_id),
username varchar(25) not null,  
FOREIGN KEY(caller_id) 
REFERENCES caller_info(caller_id),
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES caller_call_record (username)
);
$results = mysql_query($caller_escalation)
or die(mysql_error());
echo "Franchise Call Log Database successfully created!";
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic debugging

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting. If your IDE/editor doesn't provide such support, upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

try this  : missing **"** after **$caller_escalation**

```
<?php
//connect to MySQL
include("inc_connect_local.php");
mysql_select_db("Franchise Call Log");
$caller_info = "CREATE TABLE caller_info (
caller_id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,
first_name varchar(35) not null, 
Last_name varchar(35) not null, 
franchise varchar(25) not null)
";
$results = mysql_query($caller_info) or die (mysql_error());

//create "caller_call_record" table
$caller_call_record = "CREATE TABLE caller_call_record (
(call_record_id int(11) not null,
Call_Description varchar(50),
franchise_id int(10) not null,
Email varchar(40) not null, 
Username varchar(25) primary key not null)
";
$results = mysql_query($caller_escalation)
or die(mysql_error());

//create "caller_escalation" table
$caller_escalation = "CREATE TABLE caller_escalation (
call_escalation_id int(11) unsigned auto_increment not null, 
Second_Level varchar(5) not null, 
caller_id int(11) unsigned not null, 
PRIMARY KEY(call_escalation_id),
username varchar(25) not null,  
FOREIGN KEY(caller_id) 
REFERENCES caller_info(caller_id),
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES caller_call_record (username)
)";
$results = mysql_query($caller_escalation)
or die(mysql_error());
echo "Franchise Call Log Database successfully created!";
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting says it all. You're missing a quotation mark:

```
REFERENCES caller_info(caller_id),
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES caller_call_record (username)
)"; // <-- here
```

Comment: I updated and now I am receiving this error: 
Warning: include(inc_connect_local.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\franchisecalllogdb.php on line 3

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'inc_connect_local.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\franchisecalllogdb.php on line 3
 No database selected